# Gettin error when trying to initilize signature

Tags: jquery, ajax

Cannot call methods on signature prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'draw'

I want to redraw that json code

```
{
  "lines": [
    [
      [144, 130.73],
      [144, 129.73],
      [144, 128.73],
      [145, 128.73],
      [146, 128.73],
      [147, 128.73],
      [148, 128.73]
    ]
  ]
}
```

using [signature](http://keith-wood.name/signature.html)

It is showing it cannot call methods on signature prior to initialization attempted to call method 'draw'.how to fix it.

This is my redraw signature code

```js
$('button#b1').click(function() {
  $('#redrawSignature').signature('draw', $('#signatureJSON').val());
});
```

```html
<link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="signature/jquery.signature.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min‌​.js">
</script>
<script src="signature/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/signature/excanvas.js"></script>
<script src="signature/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<script src="signature/jquery.signature.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is my all using plugins

Comment: _json (string or object) the JSON object or its string representation, as is obtained from the toJSON command._

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an old question but this plugin is still good enough to be used for signature, so here is the solution, in case some else came up with the same issue.

```
// redraw_sign is the the div where you will show your signature
$('#redraw_sign').signature('enable');

// "json_sign" is where your json of the signature is. for test you can pass the above json value instead of $('#json_sign').val() in the following.

$('#redraw_sign').signature('draw', $('#json_sign').val());
$('#redraw_sign').signature('disable');
```

if the above code throws an error or initialize before 'enable' then put the first line as following.

```
$('#redraw_sign').signature().signature('enable');
```

Hopefully, it will help someone.